# Python into Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I'm new to python and I need to get some information and data from python into an excel document.

```
import csv
class_name = input("What class are you in?")
name = input("Name")

score = 0
print ("What's 1 + 2")
answer = int(input("What's the correct answer?"))
if answer == 3:
   print("Congratulations!")
   score = score + 1
else:
   print("Wrong answer")

if class_name == ('1'):
scoreRecords.append([name,score])
csvfile = open('Class.1 records.csv','a',newline='')
scoreWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
scoreWriter.writerows(coreResults)
csvfile.close()
```

I need to get the two variables listed above into an excel document with them as headings and names and class_names need to continuously be added below the appropriate column. However nothing is happening and errors are coming up.

The question has now been answered but to anyone else struggling with what I was asking and wanted to learn how to do this, basically I wanted to use the import csv function, to move three variables from a python quiz onto an excel document with the variable names at the top and the corresponding values be outputted beneath the correct variable name. Hopefully this has now cleared any confusion.

Comment: see this: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! as it's your first question it is important that you know that we're here to help, not to do your homework. Please, update your question with your own attempt at trying to solve this problem and other users will give your feedback on improving that to solve your problem. When you find that one answer satisfy you, please press the check mark on the side of that answer. Have fun.

Comment: Are you trying to enter multiple entries? Also where does score come from?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to add multiple entries. And I just updated my question so that should show where the score comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install a suitable Excel module if you wish to produce native `xlsx` files. The following should help to get you started if you choose to use [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) to create your `xlsx` file:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

class_name = raw_input("What class are you in? ")
name = raw_input("Name ")

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(row=1, column=1, value="Class name")
ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value="Name")

ws.cell(row=2, column=1, value=class_name)
ws.cell(row=2, column=2, value=name)

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

This would give you the following:

[image: Excel output example]

This was tested using Python 2.7.9

---

Based on your updated question, hopefully the following will help you. You seem to be starting to develop some kind of quiz, as such you will need to spend some time developing which questions you would like to ask.

One thing to note, it is easier to use Python's `with` statement when dealing with files, this will automatically ensure that `close` is called at the end:

```
import csv
import os

with open('Class.1 records.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Write the csv header row
    csv_output.writerow(['Class name', 'Name', 'Score'])

    score = 0

    while True:
        class_name = input("What class are you in? (Or type q to quit) ")

        if class_name == 'q':
            break

        name = input("Name: ")

        print ("What's 1 + 2")
        answer = int(input("What's the correct answer? "))

        if answer == 3:
            print("Congratulations!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print("Wrong answer")

        csv_output.writerow([class_name, name, score])
```

So the script would work for example as follows:

```
What class are you in? (Or type q to quit) 9
Name: Fred
What's 1 + 2
What's the correct answer? 0
Wrong answer
What class are you in? (Or type q to quit) 8
Name: Wilma
What's 1 + 2
What's the correct answer? 3
Congratulations!
What class are you in? (Or type q to quit) q
```

Giving you the following CSV file contents:

```
Class name,Name,Score
9,Fred,0
8,Wilma,1
```

Tested using Python 3.4.3

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry if my previous question was vague, however I have now edited it to see if it can be done using import csv. My current attempt is in the new edit as well, however I can't get it working. If you know how to do this using csv it would be greatly appreciated if you could let me know. Thanks an sorry again if my question was vague.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, what errors do you see, but the first probable problem is a broken indentation in your `if class_name == ('1')` clause.

Second: you are trying to append to `scoreRecords`, but `scoreRecords` is not defined.

Third: Use `writerow` method on `scoreWriter` to write a list of your `name` and `score` variables to the file.